# C#: Como identificar el primer digito de cada numero en un vector para contar cuantos numeros empiezan igual?

Tags: c#, array, .net, string

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buen dia.

Tengo este problema, supongo es simple pero no lo he podido resolver y tengo un dia en eso, tengo un programa que acepta 10 numeros y los ingresa en un vector, pero necesito saber cuantos numeros de estos 10 empiezan con el numero 3, cuando hago el codigo me cuanta todos los tres que hay, si por ejemplo se introduce "33" dice que dos numeros empiezan en 3, lo he hecho utilizando string e int con el mismo resultado. Si me pudieran ayudar, Gracias.

```
using System;

public class Example{

    public static void Main(){
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Programa que acepta 10 numeros y muestra cuantos de estos empiezan con 3.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        int[] n1 = new int [10];
        int cont = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

            Console.Write("Digite el {0} numero: ",x+1);
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n1[10]);

            int z = n1[x]%10;


            if(z == 3){

                cont++;

            }

        }
        Console.Write(cont);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}
```

Con string

```
class programa22{

    public static void Main(){
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Programa que acepta 10 numeros y muestra cuantos de estos empiezan con 3.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        string[] n1 = new string[10];
        int cont = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

            Console.Write("Digite el {0} numero: ",x+1);
            n1[x] = Console.ReadLine();

            char delimiter = '3';
            string[] substrings = n1[x].Split(delimiter);

            foreach (var substring in substrings)
            cont++;

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        cont = cont - 10;
        Console.Write("La cantidad de numeros que empiezan con 3 es "+cont);

     Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: solo te pediria que mires el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos. Bienvenido! podrias agregar que datos metes y que da como resultado, asi todos estamos viendo lo mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tomando el primer ejemplo que pusiste, deberias adaptar el codigo de la siguiente manera

principalmente tenias un error en

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n1[10]);
```

donde le estabas asignando el valor en el indice `10` de tu array y no en la posición correspondiente al ciclo for (deberías usar la variable **x**)

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n1[x]);
```

tu codigo del main, deberia quedar asi

```
Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("Programa que acepta 10 numeros y muestra cuantos de estos empiezan con 3.");
Console.WriteLine();

int[] n1 = new int[10];
int cont = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    Console.Write("Digite el {0} numero: ", x + 1);
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n1[x]);

    var numberAsString = Convert.ToString(n1[x]);

    if (numberAsString == "3" || numberAsString.Substring(0, 1) == "3")
        cont++;
}

Console.Write(cont);
Console.ReadKey();
```

debes convertir tu entero ingresado a `string` y luego verificar si dicha variable == "3" o si comienza con "3", esto es posible gracias a la función `Substring` que permite tomar el primer valor de tu string (0,1)

Answer (score 2):

Yo usaría esta función..

```
private bool empiezaConTres(int numero)
    {
        int i = Math.Abs(numero);
        while (i >= 10)
            i /= 10;

        return (i == 3);
    }
```

Luego la consultas de la siguiente manera

```
empiezaConTres(33); //responde True
empiezaConTres(43); // responde False
```

En tu caso

```
if(empiezaConTres(n1[x]){cont++;}
//Si retorna verdadero, aumentas el
```

Comment: No sería más sencillo escribir `return (i == 3);`?

Comment: @Xam toda la razón, ahí lo modifiqué :D

Answer (score 1):

Bueno yo también me animo a presentar otra solución utilizando `string`s.

```
using System;

namespace Numeros
{
    class Programa
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();   
            Console.WriteLine("Programa que acepta 10 números y muestra cuantos de estos empiezan con 3.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            var numeros = new int [10];
            int cont = 0;
            string str = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                do{
                    Console.Write("Digite el {0} numero:\t", i + 1);
                    str = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (!Int32.TryParse(str, out numeros[i])) {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR. Solo puede ingresar números.");
                    }                   

                } while (!Int32.TryParse(str, out numeros[i]));             

                var cadena = numeros[i].ToString();

                if (cadena.Length > 1) {
                    cadena = cadena.Remove(1);                                      
                }                           
                if (cadena == "3") {
                    cont++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("La cantidad de números que empiezan con 3 es:\t{0}", cont);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }       
    }
}
```

Para empezar he hecho unos pequeños cambios con respecto al nombre de las variables. En lugar de `n1` he puesto `numeros` y como variable para recorrer los elementos del array he puesto el clásico `i`.

En segundo lugar, como veo que estás utilizando el método `TryParse`, es bueno aprovecharse de que éste retorna un booleano, para validar que cada elemento del array que es ingresado sea efectivamente un número. Vale señalar que en este caso, para evitar un `do-while` dentro de un bucle `for`, lo mejor sería refactorizar la validación de cada elemento ingresado en un método propio (eso te lo dejo como tarea).

Una vez que el número ha sido validado, procedemos a convertirlo en una cadena. Después analizamos si la longitud de la cadena es mayor que 1. En tal caso, procedemos a usar el método [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx), removiendo cada caracter del array desde la posición 1 hasta el final. A continuación, verificamos si la cadena obtenida (que tiene longitud 1) es igual a `"3"`.

Acá es bueno señalar porque primero verificamos si la longitud de la cadena es mayor que 1. Esto es debido a que el método `Remove` arroja una excepción del tipo `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` si es que la posición desde donde empezamos no existe.

Finalmente, es bueno resaltar que la verificación de aquellos números que empiezan en 3 debería refactorizarse en un método propio, como por ejemplo, es hecho en otra de las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a aportar mi granito con LinQ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] n1 = new int [10];

            //Relleno los numeros rapido, tu haz a tu manera
            Random ran = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < n1.Length; i++)
                n1[i] = ran.Next(100);


            //Que queremos buscar
            string strPattern = "3";

            //Aqui hacemos la cuenta
            int nCount = n1.Where(x=>x.ToString().Substring(0,1) == strPattern).Count();


            //Comprobacion
            n1.ToList().ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Se han encontrado {0} repeticiones",nCount));
        }
    }
}
```

Te dejo un enlace para probarlo

[Ejemplo](http://rextester.com/OOSM28949)